# Riak pre-commit hook in Erlang?

Tags: erlang, riak, pre-commit-hook

How would I write a pre-commit hook to change all of the letters in the value of my key/value pairs to be ALL UPPERCASE in a particular bucket?

Comment: In other words, if I add key1 with value "the quick brown fox", when I retrieve key1, I get back "THE QUICK BROWN FOX".

Answer (score 1):

Using this example of pre-commit hook: https://github.com/basho/riak_function_contrib/blob/master/hooks/pre-commit/js/validate_json.js, you should be very close to a solution, using the standard `value.toUpperCase();`.

Answer (score 1):

With Erlang it can be implemented like this: https://gist.github.com/2422852